# Basic Form In Flask Causing HTTP 400 - Python 3.5

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x, flask, html

I am new and have spent hours trying to setup a form in Flask for Python 3.5. I want the user to be able to enter a temperature setpoint and click submit button, and have the value stored in a variable.
I have this code in a template file called `index.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p><font size="6">Jewell Hot-Tub Controller</font>
    <br>
    <font size="4">Water Temperature: {{water_temp}}</p>
    <br>
    <font size="4">Set Point: {{set_point}}</p>
    <br>
    <font size="4">Enter New Set Point:</p>
    <form class="form-newtemp" method="get" action="/ChangeTemp">
        <input type="text" id="new_sp" name="new_sp" size="5" placeholder="New Temp." required>
        <input id="1submit" type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this code in the "flask-test.py" file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', water_temp='12345')

@app.route('/ChangeTemp', methods=['GET'])
def process():
    new = request.form['new_sp']
    return 'New set point is:' + new
```

Entering "27" in the `textbox` sends the browser to a `400 Bad Request` page at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/ChangeTemp?new_sp=27
```

Why does this change a bad request error, rather than returning the value? The tutorials I saw used `POST`, but I used `GET`, does this require different syntax?
Also, please let me know if anything is messy, or done wrong.
Thank you!

EDIT: I also tried "request.form.get('new-sp', new)" and this causes a 500 internal server error.

Comment: look at the end of the url, you are changing it and not ready for that change. edit your form to use `POST` method for sending the form and your url to get a `POST` method, or add needed edit's on the url.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Could you dumb it down for me please?

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple ways to fix your problem. i guess the fastest way is:

```
<form class="form-newtemp" method="post" action="{{ url_for('process')}}">
```

and then

```
@app.route('/ChangeTemp', methods=['POST])
def process():
    new = request.form['new_sp']
    return 'New set point is:' + new
```

or you can go with not changing your template and:

```
@app.route('/ChangeTemp', methods=['GET'])
def process():
    new = request.args.get('new_sp')
    return 'New set point is:' + new
```